# CheckMark on android studio?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-studio, intellij-idea

This is the regular logo:

[image]

Often times, the android logo changes to have a check mark on it.

[image]

But, when I check, it signifies nothing. Gradle is still running...etc. What does this checkmark signify?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

On Intellij IDEA the checkmark usually appears when a background indexing task has been completed.

To test, you could do a `File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart` after which Intellij should re-build it's cache (which is noticeable at the bottom) :

[image]

While the background task is running, the Icon has a progress bar (on OSX):

[image]

And once that completes, the green checkmark on the Intellij Icon

[image]

which signifies that the indexing task has completed

Comment: Oh okay. What are some examples of background indexing tasks?

Comment: An example would be rebuilding the index for maven repositories. Not sure if applicable in your case. You should be able to see the list of these processes if you click on the `x process running` as in the above snapshot